# how to record keystrokes

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

This is within blender. In game, I am allowing a player to type out words for items. I need to be able to sense keystrokes in game. I have seen this done before in BGE but I don't know the particular code. my question is what is the code to sense keystrokes within python, so I don't have to make a billion sensors

I know this is a noob question but I need to know how to sense keystrokes so I can recognize words in an application I'm designing. for example, what is the code for sensing when the "k" button is pressed?

Comment: Is this a question about Blender or is it unrelated?

Comment: Sir I have changed the wording and made it more specific. I'd appreciate if you didn't make my questions go down on the list because of a mistake. you make it harder to get it answered.

Comment: @c0mlink thanks for taking the time to make your question clearer. Some  questions get closed down when are confusing or there is not enough context, once edited they can be re-opened. It is nothing personal.

Comment: @cegaton thankyou for reopening my question. No hard feelings anywhere around, I will make sure I'm clearer in the future.